# The bootstrap-select element gets hidden by parent element

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

[image: the dropdown before click to open]

[image: after click]

Hello, I am using the bootstrap-select.js plugin in my project the problem with this select element is that when I open the dropdown it hides under the parent element and creates a scroll, I want to make it visible to overflow the parent element and be visible, I tried to add style (z-index and overflow) to the select element itself but it didn't work then I tried to change the style of the dropdown elements made by the plugin, it also didn't work.

Comment: Much easier to help if you can create a snippet or plunkr that shows the issue

Comment: look for the normal range column in the first image, there is a select element; when the element is clicked the dropdown opens as you can see in the second image circled by red line.

Comment: @Kinglish is saying that it will be easier to find an answer if people could see your code. Thanks BSK